# How can I setup a Database connection for Selenium-WebDriver?

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid

If I run Selenium-WebDriver testcase it runs with the actual database which is configured for the application. But I want to setup a separate database for Selenium-WebDriver testcase For eg. "TestDB". When running the test case WebDriver should use TestDB. Is this possible?

If it possible, Do we need to configure this in any configuration file (*.xml) or anyother way to do this?

Please help me?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is not possible if you want that done only by selenium

Comment: Ok Thanks. Can you show me the sample code?

Comment: ? I said it is NOT possible. So I can't show you sample code

Comment: Yes, I know. i asked you the sample code for using only selenium not webdriver

Comment: It is NOT possible with the Selenium-framework. Just set up a copy of your software with your dummy database and run your tests on that.

Comment: This is dependent entirely on what kind of website this is. For example, we use an ASP.NET Forms website, whereby the Selenium tests run on a local Windows server, and have a single configuration value in it's app.config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a copy of your application configured to your 'TestDB' for testing purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Put a extra request parameter with html request. Example : `http://www.abcd.com/?seleniumTest=true`

*seleniumTest* parameter will only visible with selenium requests.

Capture this parameter in application and select the database on the basis of request parameter provided by selenium. If `true` map a test database, otherwise production.

Hope this works.